# How to make Selenium test pass when two images are very similar?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rmagick

I want to compare 2 images that seem to be the same when see by eyes but their pixel are a little bit different. When use selenium and rmagick to compare these 2 images, I always got false result, but I want to get pass result because these content of images are the same when looking by eyes. Does any suggestion for my case? Thanks

Please see some images for example:

the image 1 and image 2 are croped from screenshot of 2 monitors that have different resolution when running selenium.

image 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ch1.png

image2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogjfz.png

Comment: This should be possible, as you can add a fuzz factor in rmagick's compare command. However, there are lots of ways that images can be "the same". Could you provide an example of two similar images (size them down if large), and one you would wish to say was actually different? Please include them in the question if you can, not links.

Comment: I do not have enough Reputation to include images so please take a look my images by links. I also have 2 other images are very similar: Image 3 and image 4 are very similiar

image 3: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2JQJG.png
 
image 4 http://i.stack.imgur.com/ICSQG.png. Please give me some idea about them

Comment: The first pair of images are screenshots, with the same content, but one has a white border. The second pair are offset from each other. Is that also how Selenium needs to process them? Do you know in advance how much the offset and bordering/scaling effects are?

Comment: I've just got familiar with rmagick so I do not know so far? Could you explain for me? Thanks.

Comment: With these images, I do not think I know enough to help. However, take a look at Rmagick's compare_channel method: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#compare_channel - it works well provided the pixels are aligned between the two images. Depending on how you fetch the images, you may need to do extra work, such as cropping and resizing first

Comment: I tried to many way resize the image before comparing images but it always gets failed. Does anyone have any other suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli would be the way to go when you are required to compare images. 
Have a look @ the video named "Webdriver & Sikuli integration" in this page http://www.sikuli.org/testing.html

Comment: I use selenium and ruby. could you show me how can I setup sikuli and config it for using selenium and ruby. Thanks.

Comment: @Popo: Sikuli has a good web community. Googling around should provide good documentation & videos

Comment: @Popo: Did Sikuli work for you? If yes, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Visual CI](http://visualci.com) may serve your needs.
It will allow you to set ignored regions (For random data) as well as how exact should the match be.

Although, I don't believe it has a Ruby plugin, you will have to use the public REST api.